# Matlab solving digamma function

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I am trying to solve a function in Matlab: `digamma(x) - log(x/5) = 0`

I tried `sol = solve(psi(x)-log(x/5),x)`, but the digamma function `psi` is not compatible with the `solve` function.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Works for me in R2013a. Have you defined `x` with `syms x` before calling `solve`? And what `version` of Matlab are you using? What does `which sym/psi` return?

Comment: @anjruu `??? Error using ==> psi
Input must be single or double.`

Comment: @horchler Sorry I forgot to mention. My Matlab version is R2011a. I did put a `syms x` before calling `solve`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`sym/psi`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/psi.html) function [was added](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/release-notes.html#bs17m4_-1) to the Symbolic Math toolbox in Matlab version R2011b so it's not a surprise that you can't get it to work in R2011a.

If you can't upgrade, here are two things to try. First, although you can't call `psi` for symbolic inputs, it's possible that the symbolic engine in R2011a still knows about this function. I don't guarantee that it will work, but you can try this:

```
x = evalin(symengine,'float(solve(psi(x)-log(x/5),x))')
```

By the way, you may wish to consider setting `assumptions` – the `x` returned is different if you specify `syms x real` as the equation has multiple roots. If the above works, then you can call a vectorized version of the symbolic `psi` with:

```
psisym = @(x)evalin(symengine,['map(' char(sym(x)) ',psi)'])
```

Otherwise, you'll have to solve this equation numerically (`solve` gives an answer in terms of a number anyways). This is not a bad option as long as you're assuming that `x` is real and positive. Using [`fzero`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fzero.html) and the numeric version of [`psi`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/psi.html):

```
f = @(x)psi(max(x,realmin))-log(max(x,realmin)/5)
x = fzero(f,1)
```

returns

```
x =

0.407621610906987
```

I used `max(x,realmin)` to ensure that `x` never gets too small (as long as the the initial guess for `fzero` is large enough, it may not be needed). An `x` close to zero is `psi(0)-log(0)`, which is `NaN` and would result in an error from `fzero`.